# unique data v-model vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

In my **template** select field:

```
li(v-for="user in users", :id="'user_' + user.id")
  .user-management(@click="toggleShowUser(user)", :id="'user' + user.id")
    select(v-model="selected" :options="options")
```

in my vue component:

```
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      options: [
        {
         value: 'option1',
         label: 'Option 1',
         iconLeft: 'user'
        },
      ],
      selected: ['option1']
    },
    toggleShowUser(user) {
      this.$set(this.selected, 0, "5ad0ac33a8abbc3fe4ce2863")
    }
  }
}
```

The problem is that `this.selected` value is seted in all users select fields in template.

I want set this value in specific user select field with specific id.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the index to the toggle function:

```
li(v-for="user in users", :id="'user_' + user.id")
  .user-management(@click="toggleShowUser(user))", :id="'user' + user.id")
    select(v-model="selected.includes(user.id)" :options="options")
```

And update the function code:

```
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      options: [],
      selected: [],
    },
    toggleShowUser(user) {
      if (this.selected.includes(user.id)) {
        // remove
        this.selected = this.selected.filter(id => id !== user.id);
      } else {
        // insert
        this.selected.push(user.id);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, i'm getting: `[Vue warn]: Property or method "index" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive` and `console.log(index)` is `undefined`

Comment: Did you add it in the `v-for`? `v-for="(user, index) in users"`

Comment: Thank you, yes i did add it. The problem is i need `selected` like an array instead of an object :(.

Comment: Sure, declare it as an array, works the same. I have updated the answer.

Comment: Sorry, i mean, i need `v-model="selected"`. I've edited my question with an example :). Thank you!

Comment: You mean you can't change `select(v-model="selected"`  to `select(v-model="selected[index]"`?

Comment: Exactly! that's correct. I can not change selected array format because it depends on other method :(! With your solution i'm receiving this format : `["5ad0ac33a8abbc3fe4ce2863", __ob__: Observer] 0:"5ad0ac33a8abbc3fe4ce2863"`, and i need this format `['5ad0ac33a8abbc3fe4ce2863']`

Comment: I see. Check the updated answer. Notice I changed `v-model` and the method. And I'm assuming `5ad0ac33a8abbc3fe4ce2863` is `user.id`.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to create a new property for each iteration in order to find the selected value. There are 2 possible options you can try -

```
li(v-for="user in users", :id="'user_' + user.id")
  .user-management(@click="toggleShowUser(user)", :id="'user' + user.id")
    select(v-model="selected[user.id]" :options="options")

    export default {
      data() {
        return {
          options: [],
          selected: []
        },
        toggleShowUser(user) {
          this.$set(this.selected[user.id], "5ad0ac33a8abbc3fe4ce2863")
        }
      }
    }
```

or

```
li(v-for="user in users", :id="'user_' + user.id")
  .user-management(@click="toggleShowUser(user)", :id="'user' + user.id")
    select(v-model="user.selected" :options="options")


export default {
  data() {
    return {
      options: [],
    },
    toggleShowUser(user) {
      this.$set(user.selected, "5ad0ac33a8abbc3fe4ce2863")
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, how are component fields?

Comment: Sorry I am not able to understand what do you mean by component fields!

Comment: yes, i mean in `options: []` and `selected: {}` fields and  `toggleShowUser` method. Thank you!